# How to use wildcard in CSS and recognize attribute as own selector

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, css-selectors

In my scenario I have a html table with many cells, some of them got classes like `hov1`, `hov2`, ..., `hov42`, ..., up to `hov920`.

This is a small table, where the darker green cells (`hov1`) are being hovered and the light green (`hov2`) are not hovered (runs with Javascript, works really well, unless the table gets bigger).
[image]

```
...
<td class="hov0" style="background-color: rgba(0, 200, 0, 0.1);">AA</td>
<td">00</td>
<td class="hov2" style="background-color: rgba(0, 200, 0, 0.1);">BB</td>
<td class="hov2" style="background-color: rgba(0, 200, 0, 0.1);">CC</td>
...
```

I know, that i can use css wildcards, to add a hover-effect for all classes, which contain `hov`. But I only want to hover my classes and not all `hov`-classes.
Is it possible to filter additional the numbers, so only `hov1` or `hov42` are getting the hover effect in CSS. As far as I know there are only two solutions:

CSS (bad Style?):

```
hov1:hover, hov2:hover, hov3:hover ... hov99:hover {
  background: rgba(0, 200, 0, 0.5);
}
```

jQuery (very laggy, crashed my browser):

```
$(this).addClass("hov" + x);
$(this).hover(function(e) {
  $(".hov" + x).css("background-color",e.type === "mouseenter"?"rgba(0, 200, 0, 0.5)":"rgba(0, 200, 0, 0.1)")
})
```

Are there other options to solve this sophisticated.

Comment: `[class*="hov"]:not(.hov1):not(.hov42)` ?

Comment: These two were only examples: The numbers are going from 0 to 920 (maximal cells). E.g. I hover `hov3`, I don't want the hover-effect on all other elements. Sorry if I have not expressed myself clearly.

Comment: You would normally add a *new* class to the ones you want affected

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here to be honest. First of all, `style` directly on elements is not best practice; add a class to that and then style it in your stylesheet. Secondly, why not just have 1 `hov` class for elements you want styling on hover? (JSFiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/dys8otba/)

Comment: The use case here is very unclear to me. Unless each cell of your table has a different hover effect, it seems very unusual to introduce 920 new classes when u only effectively use 1 of them for 1 hover effect on 1 element.

Comment: Is there any consistency about how the classes been added? For example, each column has its own tenth for example?

Comment: These are groups of cells, which should get the same hover effect, if I hover over one of these cells. Because there are 920 cells, there can be 920 groups (which is really unlikely, but it could happen). There is no consistency whatsoever.

Comment: Do you want to add the hover effect to all cells with the same `.hov*` class or just for the one row ? And do the hover effects differ ?

Comment: The hover effect can be always the same for `.hov*`, but if I hover over `.hov1`, then only all cells with the same class `.hov1` should get a effect and all other `.hov*` like `.hov2`, `.hov3`, etc. should be ignored.

Comment: Look at my updated answer for a solution to that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to trigger the hover on all elements with the same class and still retain a very general CSS without hundreds of classes (you still need them in your HTML), you can simpply use the class attribute of the currently hovered element to target all elements with that class:

```
$("[class^='linked']").on('mouseenter', function() {
    $( '.' + $(this).attr('class') ).addClass('hovered');
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $("[class^='linked']").removeClass('hovered');
});
```

```js
$("[class^='linked']").on('mouseenter', function() {
    $( '.' + $(this).attr('class') ).addClass('hovered');
}).on('mouseleave', function() {
    $("[class^='linked']").removeClass('hovered');
});
```

```css
th {
  background: lightblue;
}

th, td {
  padding: 5px 10px;  
}

[class^="linked"].hovered {
  background: rgba(0, 200, 0, 0.5);
}

[class^="linked"] {
  background: rgba(0, 200, 0, 0.1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>00</th>
      <th>01</th>
      <th>02</th>
      <th>03</th>
      <th>04</th>
      <th>05</th>
      <th>06</th>
      <th>07</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="linked1">00</td>
      <td class="linked1">6D</td>
      <td class="linked2">64</td>
      <td class="linked1">74</td>
      <td class="linked1">4D</td>
      <td class="linked1">6F</td>
      <td class="linked2">20</td>
      <td>2B</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="linked1">2F</td>
      <td class="linked2">76</td>
      <td class="linked1">30</td>
      <td>73</td>
      <td>0D</td>
      <td class="linked1">0A</td>
      <td class="linked2">C2</td>
      <td class="linked3">00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution, but it won't work in my case, because the "grouped" cells (same class for hovering) can spread over rows.

Comment: have a look at the updated answer for a working example

Comment: Yeah, that is nice. Works way better than my JS solution and won't waste my css. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody stops you to add as many classes to your element as you wish. This way you can filter them at your convenience.

Also, if you choose to use wildcards, be as  specific as possible.

```css
div[class*="colored"] {
  background: yellow;
}

div[class*="colored"]:hover.should-flash {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="colored1 should-flash">1</div>
<div class="colored2">2</div>
<div class="x">4</div>
<div class="colored3 should-flash">3</div>
```

Comment: `Nobody stops you to add as many classes to your element as you wish` how do you know? Maybe OP doesn't have control on the HTML.. The answer is a guess.. Sorry..

Comment: The question is does he really need 920 classes ? That is very unlikely and solving that will most likely solve his issue ... you basically just added a new class in addition to his 920

Comment: I assumed, the OP does have control on HTML. That information doesn't come through.

Comment: I have control over the html. I generate the table dynamic with jQuery and have full access.
But 920 classes sounds bad, therefore I am asking, if there is a better solution.

Comment: @p4cx, then, you should add the differentiating classes there. Also, as others told, I'd check whether I need so many classes.

Comment: @MoshFeu OP *clearly* has control over the js, so can add classes that way.